# C# Extract json object from mixed data text/js file

Tags: c#, json

I need to parse reactjs file in `main.451e57c9.js` to retrieve version number with C#.
This file contains mixed data, here is little part of it:

```
.....inally{if(s)throw i}}return a}}(e,t)||xe(e,t)||we()}var Se=
JSON.parse('{"shortVersion":"v3.1.56"}')
,Ne="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA
AASAAAAAqCAYAAAATb4ZSAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEw.....
```

I need to extract json data of `{"shortVersion":"v3.1.56"}`

The last time I tried to simply find the string `shortVersion` and return a certain number of characters after, but it seems like I'm trying to create the bicycle from scratch. Is there proper way to identify and extract json from the mixed text?

```
public static void findVersion()
{
    var partialName = "main.*.js";
    string[] filesInDir = Directory.GetFiles(@pathToFile, partialName);

    var lines = File.ReadLines(filesInDir[0]);

    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filesInDir[0]))
    {
        string keyword = "shortVersion";
        int indx = line.IndexOf(keyword);

        if (indx != -1)
        {
            string code = line.Substring(indx + keyword.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(code);
        }
    }
}
```

RESULT

```
":"v3.1.56"}'),Ne="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA.....
```

Comment: Do you need the react version? if so why not `import React from 'react';
let a = React.version`

Comment: It is project folder like `/web/static/js/`. I need to get version in C#

Comment: Given the code snippet presented `var Se=` would `Se.shortVersion` not contain the version value here?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I think you missed a bit, author wants to read some js file with c# code and extract a value from json string inside of this js file.

Comment: Yea, I read too fast when I saw the "react" in there.  My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
           string findJson(string input, string keyword) {
                int startIndex = input.IndexOf(keyword) - 2; //Find the starting point of shortversion then subtract 2 to start at the { bracket
                input = input.Substring(startIndex); //Grab everything after the start index

                int endIndex = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
                    char letter = input[i];
                    if (letter == '}') {
                        endIndex = i; //Capture the first instance of the closing bracket in the new trimmed input string.
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return input.Remove(endIndex+1);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(findJson("fwekjfwkejwe{'shortVersion':'v3.1.56'}wekjrlklkj23klj23jkl234kjlk", "shortVersion"));
```

You will recieve {'shortVersion':'v3.1.56'} as output

Note you may have to use `line.Replace('"', "'");`

Comment: Thank you for the alternative answer. To be honest this has better performance and it works with big file.

Answer (score 1):

Try below method -

```
 public static object ExtractJsonFromText(string mixedStrng)
    {
        for (var i = mixedStrng.IndexOf('{'); i > -1; i = mixedStrng.IndexOf('{', i + 1))
        {
            for (var j = mixedStrng.LastIndexOf('}'); j > -1; j = mixedStrng.LastIndexOf("}", j -1))
            {
                var jsonProbe = mixedStrng.Substring(i, j - i + 1);
                try
                {
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonProbe);
                }
                catch
                {                        
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Fiddle
https://dotnetfiddle.net/N1jiWH

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I wanted to achieve ^-^

Comment: Great. Please mark if the answer was usful.

Comment: So this is really great solution for small text but problem I have is when I load whole main.js file it takes long time to go through and has error like this `Length cannot be less than zero`. So in real application I can't use it.

Comment: Use this, this should be faster - https://dotnetfiddle.net/sYFvYj

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `GetFiles()` since you only need one and that returns all before you can do anything.  This should give your something you can work with here and it should be as fast as it likely can be with big files and/or lots of files in a folder (to be fair I have not tested this on such a large file system or file)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var path = $@"c:\SomePath";
        var jsonString = GetFileVersion(path);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jsonString))
        {
            // do something with string; deserialize or whatever.
            var result=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Version>>(jsonString);
            var vers = result.shortVersion;
        }
    }

    private static string GetFileVersion(string path)
    {
        var partialName = "main.*.js";
        // JSON string fragment to find: doubled up braces and quotes for the $@ string
        string matchString = $@"{{""shortVersion"":";
        string matchEndString = $@" ""}}'";
        // we can later stop on the first match
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("The directory does not exist.");
        }

        // Call the GetFileSystemInfos method and grab the first one
        FileSystemInfo info = dir.GetFileSystemInfos(partialName).FirstOrDefault();
        if (info.Exists)
        {
            // walk the file contents looking for a match (assumptions made here there IS a match and it has that string noted)
            var line = File.ReadLines(info.FullName).SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains(matchString)).Take(1).First();
            var indexStart = line.IndexOf(matchString);
            var indexEnd = line.IndexOf(matchEndString, indexStart);
            var jsonString = line.Substring(indexStart, indexEnd + matchEndString.Length);
            return jsonString;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    public class Version
    {
        public string shortVersion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I used `dir.GetFileSystemInfos(partialName).FirstOrDefault();` instead of `Directory.GetFiles(@pathToFile, partialName);` because I did not like using array item `filesInDir[0]` in this manner. But as for extracting `json` I can not use your approach because it extracts tons of other objects which I need to filter later.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to comment on another answer, this has no `filesInDir[0]` and should only return the substring with the version as a JSON string since it skips all lines without the version then captures that string until the first/next `matchEndString` value

Answer (score 0):

Use this this should be faster - https://dotnetfiddle.net/sYFvYj

```
 public static object ExtractJsonFromText(string mixedStrng)
        {
            string pattern = @"\(\'\{.*}\'\)";
            string str = null;
            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(mixedStrng, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline))
            {
                if (match.Success)
                {

                    str = str + Environment.NewLine + match;
                }
            }
           

            return str;
        }
```

Comment: It definitely will be faster, but problem is that using Regex it will give me lot of other objects. As you may know `main.*.js`  is minified almost whole Reactjs app.